# Is it a good practice to use one URL for entire application in ASP.NET MVC Project?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that use ajax for load part of page in entire application use `@Html.Partial`.My client request's is the website should have only one URL.I'm at the beginning of the project and it is a big clinic management system. I want my codes be reusable for other projects and have a nice performance. Can i do that with this approach?

Comment: A url is sort of just the first parameter of a querystring. It helps with the separation of the code. If it's a public website, then search engine will have a hard time indexing it.

Comment: Your client wants an SPA (single page application). There's lots of google results on how to do this if you don't want to use a framework like Angular or React, though I'd recommend using Angular, personally. This question however is far too broad for stack overflow and is totally opinion  =)